# how to store in a global variable c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

How do I store the `voterid` into a global variable so I can use it on another form? I will use this `voterid` in order to check if the voter has already voted.

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
OleDbCommand comd1 = new OleDbCommand();
comd1.Connection = connection;
comd1.CommandText = "SELECT VoterID FROM tbl_voter where Uname='" +
                    txt_user.Text + "' and Pword='" + txt_pass.Text + "'";
voterid = Convert.ToString(comd1.ExecuteScalar());
MessageBox.Show(voterid);

connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();

this.Hide();
vote form3 = new vote();
form3.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You could create a `public static` property in whatever class you're dealing with. Then from the other form, you would reference `whateverclass.whateverproperty`. It's not a great OO design though. A better solution would be to pass the information to the other form itself or at least something to tell the other from where to get the info. The static property solution creates what's known as a "tightly coupled" situation and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Very broad question with many solutions. You could look into static classes/methods for some examples.

Comment: @itsme86 thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking about a Windows Forms application, and by "global" you mean "common across the process," then you can use a [static variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162(v=vs.71).aspx).

In this example i create a special class just to hold static variables, and declare one field and one property that will be available to your program and will hold one and only one value across the entire process.

```
static class GlobalVariables
{
    static public string SomeVariable { get; set ; }  //As a property
    static public string SomeOtherVariable;           //As a field
}
```

Note that if your program is multi-threaded, it may be a good idea to put a critical section around static variables, like this:

```
static class GlobalVariables
{
    static private string LockObject = new Object();
    static private string _someVariable;

    static public string SomeVariable 
    { 
        get
        {
            lock(LockObject) { return _someVariable; }
        }
        set
        {
            lock(LockObject) { _someVariable = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't each member also have the static keyword?

Comment: Man you guys are so fast, I was still in the middle of typing!  Yes you are correct.

Comment: Wrong order though!

Comment: Eh, Resharper can screw itself.  The c# specification will allow any order of the access modifiers, and `static` to me is more important than `public` or `private`.

Comment: Wow, how come I never noticed that before

Comment: Thank you all guys, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Application state belongs in the application state object. WinForms apps don't have one of these but you could create an AppState class and put an instance in a static property on the Program class. You can then define whatever global state you like as strongly type properties of AppState and reference them from anywhere in your program as `Program.AppState.MyGlobalStronglyTypedValue`

You can then put the (de)serialisation logic in the AppState class if you need to persist app state.

Comment: I am not sure that all global variables should be conceived to be part of application state.

Comment: I am. Variables hold state, that's _all_ they do. If it's not _global_ state then why is it in a global variable? Feel free to offer a counterexample if one comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: For example, a singleton will want its own static variable not held in AppState, or a cache provider will want to store cache in private variables that it manages, or a static reference to a stateless service should be held somewhere else.  Putting all your global variables in one place just because they are global would lead to a confusing structure and violate OCP and SRP.

Comment: I think the basis of our disagreement is interpretation of the word global. The things you are describing are not global, they are shared. It's not the same. You're talking about defining scopes. If you can meaningfully do that then the items aren't global, or at least should not be.